# Row-Level Formula (Is status formula if true = Out of SLA and not true = In SLA)

Tags: formula, reporting, report-formula

Could someone help me with the following syntax I try to work out.
Request:
I try to create formula when status of case is 'On Hold Pending Customer' and the time of last CAL and the time now is outside 1 hour the case is 'Out of SLA', if the case last CAL is within 1 hour it is 'In SLA'.

Formula:

```text
IF(AND(status, 'On Hold Pending Customer',Case.TimeSinceLastRelevantCALHours__c-TIMENOW())>1,'Out of Sla','In SLA')
```

And receive below error:
[image]

Thank you in advance for helping me out :)

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SSE! can you confirm if Status field a standard field and is it a picklist field? Also you have given output type as Date/time But as per your requirement it should be Text I guess

Comment: Yes status is indeed a picklist field.

Comment: But if I use text as Formula Output Type it does go in error as well.

Answer (score 0):

As status is Picklist field You have to use `ISPICKVAL()` OR `TEXT()` functions to compare the results so it should be like below.

```
ISPICKVAL(STATUS, 'On Hold Pending Customer')
```

Also the AND() should have different components to be validated inside it as below.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, 'On Hold Pending Customer'), (TimeSinceLastRelevantCALHours__c-NOW())>1)
```

As said in the comment the return should be Text instead of Date/Time.

I hope with that your formula should be something as below.

```
IF(AND(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, 'On Hold Pending Customer'), (TimeSinceLastRelevantCALHours__c-NOW())>1),'Out of Sla','In SLA')
```

Note that I just modified your formula according to the syntax . you need to modify this according to your requirement

Comment: Thank you!! It worked with some modifications :)

Comment: Can I ask 1 more thing, what can I add in the syntax that if it is not status 'On Hold Pending Customer' that it shows null?

Comment: You mean to add such that if status is not On Hold Pending Customer it should return NULL?

Comment: Yes indeed, hence now all other statusses return as 'Inside SLA' but they have another status so they should not be included in the results.

Comment: (I am unfortunately not strong in formulas :( even though I did all the trailblazer modules regarding it.)

Comment: You can use another If condition in this scenerio as below. `IF(ISPICKVAL(STATUS, 'On Hold Pending Customer') if(((TimeSinceLastRelevantCALHours__c-NOW())>1),'Out of Sla','In SLA'),'')
`

Comment: Omg, yes, it worked :D thank you so much!!